# Django Apps and Python Packages Dependencies

Tags: python, django

I am new to web development. I am not familiar with Django. I have written some Python scripts which do some intense calculations and graphs plotting using Python packages such as numpy, matlibplot and so on. I want to publish it as a web application on a server to be accessed by other computers.

So I am wondering, do I need to copy all the required packages into the project directory before deploying the application to a server? Or Django will automatically handle the Python packages dependencies upon deploying?

Comment: You still need to install the packages such as `numpy`, better put them in requirements.txt and run `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Best way to do this is, create a `virtualenv` and then install django, and then pip install. Neat and clean.

Answer (score 0):

All the needed packages need to be installed on the server where is the web application running. If you have all the packages installed on your personal computer before deploy you will need to install the on the server as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create virtual environment.
A virtual environment is a tool that helps to keep dependencies required by different projects separate by creating isolated python virtual environments for them.